How to import ffmpeg in my video download algorithm using yt_dlp?
I'm developing a project to download videos from YouTube in a specified quality. I would do this using pytube, but with it I can't download videos with age restrictions. When I normally import yt_dlp, I didn't get the built-in ffmpeg installed, as I understand, and I can't download videos in all resolutions except 720p. Can I install some kind of library for audio and video merging or do I need to connect an external program (undesirable for me, as I want to buy a simple hosting that does not provide for the installation of external programs)?

Try ffmpeg.js
